# Why does the statue at the airport wear a 'cone hat' in GTA 3?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iii

Pretty sure I've seen this cone appear orange as well. This screenshot is taken from the iPad version.

[image: cone hat statue]

Furthermore, I always wondered what the text underneath is actually referring to. Does a radio station mention this 'event' in 1936?

[image: 1936]

'For those who fought for freedom. 1936'

Answer (score 7):

A Rockstar North easter egg, it's a reference to the statue of the Duke of Wellington located in Glasgow, Scotland. People often put a traffic cone on the head of the statue for a laugh.

Taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equestrian_statue_of_the_Duke_of_Wellington,_Glasgow):

> The equestrian Wellington Statue, most often featured with a traffic cone on its head, on Royal Exchange Square in Glasgow, Scotland, is one of the city's most iconic images.

[image]

Comment: It's not the only statue that regularly gets this treatment. Putting traffic cones on monuments is popular woth drunk students all over the country.